# How do you decide if a function should return data directly (via return statement) or indirectly (e.g. updating a class property) or both?

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns

I have some functions which update records in some database tables.

When I run each function I want to know **the number of records affected by each**.

I'm wondering what the most elegant way of returning this information is.

Do I return it directly from the functions as an integer like this?

```php
$result1 = $records->create();
$result2 = $records->update();
$result3 = $records->delete();

echo "1: $result1";
echo "2: $result2";
echo "3: $result3";
```

Do I return it directly using a labeled array like this?

```php
$result1 = $records->create()["number_created"];
$result2 = $records->update()["number_updated"];
$result3 = $records->delete()["number_deleted"];

echo "1: $result1";
echo "2: $result2";
echo "3: $result3";
```

Do I return it indirectly by updating a class property like this?

```php
$records->create();
$records->update();
$records->delete();

echo "1: " . $records::number_created;
echo "2: " . $records::number_updated;
echo "3: " . $records::number_deleted;
```

Or do I use a combination of the above, returning it directly and also using class properties?

When would each case be used, and how would you decide which approach to use?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please provide more complete code - e.g. complete function/method/class. ["_there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works._"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114)

Comment: Returning directly is definitely better, as any static variable will inevitably introduce a state,  which means different calls may rewrite that variable. Another approach is to represent every insert or delete with a distinct object that would contain a dynamical property

Comment: Make all your objects immutable, your life will be easier. Of course there's always some exceptions, but as a rule of thumb, immutable is better.